# Pull & Format date direct from Eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

Im trying to pull a load of results from a MySQL database and format the date string within the same query. My dates in the database are stored as yyyy-mm-dd but im being asked to pull them as dd-mm-yyyy.

Im wondering if i can pull data back and format it all in 1 or just how i would do it in general. Right now the only way i can think of is going through each result and changing date using `Carbon` but i feel like this is wrong and theres a better way.

something like: `Post::all()->format('date', 'dd-mm-yyy')`, i understand that this is highly unlikely to be a part of laravel but hopefully it gives some idea of what im after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a mutator. With a mutator you can transform any of the fields in your query to be transformed any way you want in a transparent, implicit way.

I'm not gonna code it for you, but here is the link so you can learn how to build your own:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators